# Multi category filter option in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filter

I am building an android application. Where I need to implement tab list like Flipkart Filter menu style.  I have  two recyler views (with multi select option) horizontally in a LinerLayout like this. My first recyclerview will be having list categories and onclick of each category second recyclerview will get populated with multi selection. I am able to do this with two different adapters for each.

After selecting few items in second recyclerview again i will select one more category in first recyclerview  and then seconnd recylcerview will get updated with new data. But how can i retain previous selection?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/base_background"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/app"
    android:text="Apply Filter"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Clear Filters">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Apply">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/View01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
         />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/View02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have a data structure that stores the items that were selected, and then while populating the second recyclerview you check whether the item you inserted is in the data structure or not, if it is in the data structure you select the item programatically using `recyclerViewAdapter.setSelectedItem(recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() - 1)`.